# Into redis If possibile to have a slave synched with multiple master?

Tags: redis, federation

I have different data source on different server, that write on local redis instance.

I have also a presentation layer able to show redis data .

I would like to show data on all redis instance.

Being carefully on not superimpose redis keys namespace, I Was thinking  to use replication, with multiple configuration strings as:

> slaveof *server1* 6379
>
> slaveof *server2* 6379

But only one of two is synched.

Is the any way to accomplish this task?